# how to stop execution if user forget to choose a jRadioButton in my code?

Tags: java, swing

my problem may be simple but can't get idea to fix it ,i'm working on a project
  and i put 2 radio Buttons  to select gender ;
   if user forget to determine gender how i can print error message to urge user
    determine gender? the problem in the begining of this code :

```
   private void jButton1ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String radioText="";
    if (jRadioButton1.isSelected()){radioText=jRadioButton1.getText();}
   //male   
    if (jRadioButton2.isSelected()){radioText=jRadioButton2.getText();} 
   // female      
    /*** want here if nothing selected:
     * JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"you must determine gender!");
     * and exit the code
     */
   try
   {
    String first,second,last,operation;


    int bMonth,bDay,bYear; // to set birthDay
    int aMonth,aDay,aYear; //to set admissionDate
    int fileNo,weight,height;

    first = jTextField1.getText();
    second = jTextField2.getText();
    last = jTextField3.getText();
    operation=jTextField14.getText();
    bMonth = Integer.parseInt(jTextField4.getText());
    bDay = Integer.parseInt(jTextField5.getText());
    bYear = Integer.parseInt(jTextField6.getText());

    aMonth =Integer.parseInt(jTextField7.getText());
    aDay =Integer.parseInt(jTextField8.getText());
    aYear = Integer.parseInt(jTextField9.getText());
    fileNo=Integer.parseInt(jTextField10.getText());
    weight=Integer.parseInt(jTextField12.getText());
    height=Integer.parseInt(jTextField13.getText());

    Date birth = new Date( bMonth, bDay, bYear );
    Date admissionDate = new Date( aMonth, aDay,aYear );
    Patient patient = new Patient( first, second,last,fileNo      
    ,birth,admissionDate,weight,height,radioText,operation );

    patientsArray.add(patient);


       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null,patientsArray);
       }
     catch (NumberFormatException ex)
       {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Input must be Integer!");
       }
     }
```

Comment: `if (radioText.isEmpty()) { // Error message } else { // All be good }`

Comment: @MadProgrammer the radioText is already empty by default : String radioText=" ";

Comment: @AhmedBinAbdullah Yes, that's right and if after your two `if (jRadioButtonx.isSelected()){radioText=jRadioButton1.getText();}` statements the `radioText` is still empty, then they haven't selected anything...

Comment: @MadProgrammer i think it's OK now : if (jRadioButton1.isSelected()){radioText=jRadioButton1.getText();} //male
        if (jRadioButton2.isSelected()){radioText=jRadioButton2.getText();} //female
        if (radioText.isEmpty()) { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"you must determine the gender!"); }
       else      
       try
       {
        String first,second,last,operation;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using a `ButtonGroup` with the radio buttons. This will allow you to only select on radio button at a time. Then you can check the `ButtonGroup` for the selection.

```
JRadioButton male = new JRadioButton("Male");
JRadioButton female = new JRadioButton("Female");

ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
group.add(male);
group.add(female);
```

Then in the `ActionListener` you can check the group:

```
if (group.getSelection() == null)
    // no selection has been made
```

You will need to define the `ButtonGroup` as an instance variable so you can reference it in your `ActionListener`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#radiobutton) for more information and example.